# Counting the number of contacts and remove contact button

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frameworks

I am currently learning and playing around with the use of the knockout js framework. I have a basic set of fields for contacts. I am able to add contacts without any problems. But there are two things I am having difficulties figuring out. First, a button to remove a contact(both name and phone). Second, a way to count number label the contacts. I set a label `Person` and try using `data-bind: $index` to see if I could get `Person # 1`, `Person # 2`, etc but it did not work. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dLbY7/10/)

```
var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
        return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, phone: contact.phone, alt_phone: contact.alt_phone };
    }));

    self.addContact = function() {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phone: "",
            alt_phone: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function(contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function(contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function(phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$index is not working because you are using knockout2.0.0 it doesn't have $index observable. and for deleting the contact add this code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: $parent.removeContact">Remove</a>
```

working code http://jsfiddle.net/dLbY7/12/

Comment: Great! one thing: it possible when clicking the remove to leave one set of fields of `contact`?

Comment: Yes its is possible for that you can either remove only selected value and left the value which required or remove complete record then again add the same with desired value.

Comment: Another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060667/getting-checkbox-value-from-json-object