# Getting checkbox value from json object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frameworks

I am currently learning and playing around with the use of the knockout js framework. I have a basic set of fields for contacts. I am able to add contacts without any problems. But I am having difficulties with setting the values for gender `male` and `female`.  I have declared properly but when reading the JSON object it doesn’t display any values for gender. Why is it not showing if a contact is male or female? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dLbY7/14/)

```
var initialData = [{
    firstName: "Jenny",
    lastName: "LaRusso",
    phone: "(555) 121-2121",
    alt_phone: "(555) 123-4567",
    male: false,
    female: true
}, {
    firstName: "Sensei",
    lastName: "Miyagi",
    phone: "(555) 444-2222",
    alt_phone: "(555) 999-1212",
    male: true,
    female: false
}];

var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(contacts, function (contact) {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: contact.firstName,
            lastName: contact.lastName,
            phone: contact.phone,
            alt_phone: contact.alt_phone,
            male: contact.male,
            female: contact.female
        });
    });

    self.addContact = function () {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phone: "",
            alt_phone: "",
            male: false,
            female: false
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function (contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function (contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function (phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function () {
            this.phones.remove(phone)
        })
    };

    self.save = function () {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

Comment: I think for gender selection you should use radio button not checkbox.
by having radio button you can also radio one extra field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable a checkbox in knockout.js, the correct syntax is

Declare checkbox in HTML as

```
<input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: bindName" />
```

To Enable/Disable checkbox through knockout.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {
    bindName : ko.observable(false),
};
</script>
```

Change the javascript code to

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(contacts, function (contact) {
    self.contacts.push({
        firstName: contact.firstName,
        lastName: contact.lastName,
        phone: contact.phone,
        alt_phone: contact.alt_phone,
        male: ko.observable(contact.male), /* Line Modified */
        female: ko.observable(contact.female) /* Line Modified */
    });
```

In HTML Change the code for checkbox

```
 Male <input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: male' />
 Female <input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: female' />
```

JS Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/dLbY7/15/

Comment: this works perfect. What would you suggest if I wanted to have a subcheckbox for male? For example click male checkbox and then show a checkbox that said `age range 20-30`